# Unable to handle Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, exception

I have a requirement like need to display related opportunities for a specific lead with some criterias like sic,state,city.

1.sic starts with criteria like sic in lead is 123 i need to opportunities like 123,1234

2.Sic with state

3.Sic with state & city

4.State only

5.State & city

6.City

Because i need to cover all use cases.Unfortunately my code unable to handle 3, 5,6 conditions.

Please advise me how to fix.trimed version of my code.

```
public void search()
{
    set<String> cityset=new set<String>();
     codes = new Set<String>();
    Map<String,String> citymap=new Map<String,String>();
    Map<String,String> statemap=new Map<String,String>();
    Map<String,String> Siccodes=new Map<String,String>();
    newopplist=new List<Opportunity>();
    Secondopplist=new List<Opportunity>();
    MainSic=new List<Opportunity>();
    Mainlist=new List<Opportunity>();
    MainSic=null;
    Mainlist=null;
    Secondopplist = null;
    listopp=null;
    for(Lead ld:[Select Id,City,State,SIC_Code_1__c from Lead where Id=:CurrentId ])
    {
        // cityset.add(ld.City);
        if(ld.City <> null)
        {
            citymap.put(ld.City.toUpperCase(),ld.City);
        }
        if(ld.state <> null)
        {
            statemap.put(ld.State.toUpperCase(),ld.State);
        }
        if(ld.SIC_Code_1__c <> null)
        {
        Siccodes.put(ld.SIC_Code_1__c, ld.SIC_Code_1__c);
        }
    }
    newopplist=[Select Id,Name,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,StageName,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where StageName='Closed Won' ];
    listopp=new List<Opportunity>();
    if(!Siccodes.isEmpty())
        { 
            for(String code:Siccodes.keySet())
            {
                codes.add(code + '%');
            }
        }
            for (Opportunity opp:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                     Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                     account.No_of_active_units__c from opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                     LIKE :codes ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
            {
                if(opp.account.SIC_Code__c <> null)
                {
                    listopp.add(opp);
                }
            MainSic=listopp.clone();
            }  
    for(Opportunity opp: newopplist)
    {
         if(statemap.containskey(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) && listopp.size() > 0 && listopp!= null)
        {
            listopp.clear();
            for(Opportunity opps:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,
                     Type,Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                     account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                     LIKE :codes AND Billing_State_Province__c=:statemap.get(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) 
                     and StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
            {
                System.debug('State Info with sic'+opps.Billing_State_Province__c);
                if(opps.Billing_State_Province__c <> null)
                {
                   listopp.add(opps); 
                }
                System.debug('Data in **** '+listopp);
                Mainlist=listopp.clone();
            }
        }  
        if(citymap.containsKey(opp.Billing_City__c) && Mainlist.size() > 0 && Mainlist!= null )
        {
            listopp.clear();
            for(Opportunity oppsd:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                     Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                     account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where account.SIC_Code__c 
                     LIKE :codes AND Billing_State_Province__c=:statemap.get(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) 
                     AND Billing_City__c =:citymap.get(opp.Billing_City__c) and 
                     StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
            {
                if(oppsd.Billing_City__c <> null)
                {
                    listopp.add(oppsd);
                }
            }
        } 
        else if(statemap.containskey(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) && listopp.isEmpty() && listopp.size() < 1 )
        {
            listopp.clear();
            for(Opportunity opps:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,
                             Type,Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                             account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where 
                             Billing_State_Province__c=:statemap.get(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) 
                             and StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
            {
                if(opps.Billing_State_Province__c <> null) 
                {
                    listopp.add(opps); 
                }
            }
            Secondopplist=listopp.clone();
        }  
         if(citymap.containskey(opp.Billing_City__c) && Secondopplist.size() > 0 && Secondopplist != null)
        {
            listopp.clear();
            For(Opportunity opps:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,
                     Type,Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                     account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where 
                     Billing_State_Province__c=:statemap.get(opp.Billing_State_Province__c) and 
                     Billing_City__c =:citymap.get(opp.Billing_City__c) and StageName='Closed Won' 
                     ORDER BY  account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
            {
                if(opps.Billing_City__c <> null) 
                {
                    listopp.add(opps);
                }
            }
        } 
       else if(citymap.containskey(opp.Billing_City__c) && Secondopplist.size() < 1 && Secondopplist == null)
        {
            listopp.clear();
            for(Opportunity opps:[Select Id,Name,StageName,Account.name,Number_of_Units__c,account.SIC_Code__c,Type,
                     Billing_City__c,Billing_State_Province__c,account.SIC_Industry_Name__c,
                     account.No_of_active_units__c from Opportunity where 
                     Billing_City__c =:citymap.get(opp.Billing_City__c) and 
                     StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY account.No_of_active_units__c Desc NULLS LAST Limit 10])
            {
                if(opps.Billing_City__c <> null)
                {
                    listopp.add(opps);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

My Stack Trace:

```
Time Started      6/22/2017 7:39 AM
Class             TestLeadController
Method Name       testwithSicandstatecity
Pass/Fail         Fail
Error Message   System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null 
                 object
Stack Trace Class.LeadController.search: line 120, column 1
Class.TestLeadController.testwithSicandstatecity: line 102, column 1
```

And line 120 is

> citymap.containskey(opp.Billing_City__c) && Secondopplist.size() > 0
>   && Secondopplist != null

Comment: This post apparently requires an extended discussion to resolve, which I have [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60900/discussion-on-question-by-pavan-tej-unable-to-handle-attempt-to-de-reference-a-n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three variables you de-reference in that line:

- `cityMap`
- `opp`
- `secondOppList`

You try to do a null check on this third variable, but you have the order reversed. The other two variables do not appear likely to be null.

**Protects From Null Pointer**

```
if (secondOppList != null && !secondOppList.isEmpty())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The above is essentially equivalent to:

```
if (secondOppList != null)
{
    // now you know the variable can be safely de-referenced
    // so the below line will never throw a NullPointerException
    if (!secondOppList.isEmpty())
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

**Adds No Protection**

```
if (!secondOppList.isEmpty() && secondOppList != null)
```

The above is essentially equivalent to:

```
if (!secondOppList.isEmpty())
{
    // you've already de-referenced the variable
    // and hence hit your NullPointerException

    // the below check adds no value because it is too late
    if (secondOppList != null)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

You need to check null *first*, because short-circuit evaluation will prevent any de-reference attempt in that case.